# How to create a place in Facebook using the sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an LBS app that will integrate facebook places as part of its functunality and I'm trying to find out how to bring my set of POIs to facebook so that I can have them associated with my db of POIs... any clues how to do this thru the Graph API?

Comment: it might be part of the collaboration agreement they have between the 2 companies... but so far nothing public

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create places through the API.